# How do you encrypt a laptop that does multi OS booting?

Tags: linux, windows, security, encryption, disk-encryption

I have a laptop dual booting more than one operating system. This rules out BitLocker since it only works for Windows, correct?

I tried using VeraCrypt from within the Windows side, but it did not allow me to do the entire drive.

Do I need to encrypt separately from the Windows and Linux side?

Comment: You should defer the reason you were unable to use FFE with VeraCrypt it absolutely should be possible

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in encrypting the OS partitions, yes, this will need to be done separately.   If you set aside a separate partition for data, you should be able to use a cross-platform encryption technology like Veracrypt to allow access to it from either system.

In order to do full disk encryption, a space needs to be set aside separate to the disks (actually on the disk, different partition) to execute a pre-boot environment to get the passphrase and decrypt the resources for the OS.  This can be tied in to TPM on the motherboard to provide a more secure environment - however different OS's require different pre-boot environments.